# Chrome Extension: contextMenus.create: Invalid url pattern

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Trying to make a very simple Chrome extension.  If someone right clicks on a subreddit link, there is a context option to send it to redditp.com instead.

**background.js**

```
{

function redpts(info,tab) {
    var url = info.linkUrl;
    console.log("Link " + info.selectionText + " was clicked to be redditp'd.");
    var urlp = url.replace(/reddit.com/i, "redditp.com");
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: urlp });  
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "RedditP That Shizz!",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["link"],
  "targetUrlPatterns": ["*://*reddit.com/r*"],
  "onclick" : redpts
});

}
```

The error chrome throws is that I have not pattern matched the subreddit URL properly, but I very much tried to follow the formatting instructions of the '[Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns)' google page.

Full Error:  Unchecked runtime.lastError while running contextMenus.create: Invalid url pattern '*://*reddit.com/r*'

I am a bit cross-eyed trying to see my mistake.  Thanks.

Edit:  If I comment out the targetUrlPatterns, it works as expected.

Comment: As the documentation says, you can't have variable second level domain in match patterns. Add a dot before `reddit`.

Answer (score 1):

Your url pattern should be

```
"*://*.reddit.com/r*
```

and you context menu for new chrome version look like be

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "id" : "someuniquerid",
    "title" : "RedditP That Shizz!",
    "type" : "normal",
    "contexts" : ["link"],
    "targetUrlPatterns": ["*://*.reddit.com/r*"]
  });




chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(e){
  if(e.menuItemId == 'someuniquerid') {    
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(function(tab){

        // do you work here

    });
  }
});
```